# Process finished with exit code 1 Spring Boot Intellij no other logs

Tags: java, spring-boot

I see no logs in my console
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java...

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You need to provide more information like Spring boot version, Java version, the command you are attempting to run, any output you do get.  There really isn't enough information to assist you in your question.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(YourClass.class);
            app.run(args);
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

With this, I was able to see the full error in the logs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Now it shows the exception! Why and how is Spring suppressing it??

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application.yml with bad syntax, you can obtain the error. Review your application.yml or put the code above to have more information about the exception.